# PHP & MYSQL: Register/Create an Account

Tags: php, mysql

I have code for registering (using database as well). When I input information in the form and submit, nothing happens. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

-after I fix this hopefully I can log in!

register.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>

<p><a href="register.php">Register</a> | <a href="login.php">Login</a></p>
<h3>Registration Form</h3>
<form action="" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="user"><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br /> 
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
    $user=$_POST['user'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];

    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_db('database') or die("cannot select DB");

    $query=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='".$user."'");
    $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows==0)
    {
    $sql="INSERT INTO login(username,password) VALUES('$user','$pass')";

    $result=mysqli_query($sql);


    if($result){
    echo "Account Successfully Created";
    } else {
    echo "Failure!";
    }

    } else {
    echo "That username already exists! Please try again with another.";
    }

} else {
echo "All fields are required!";
}
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Database info:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login` (
  `username` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: your wide open to being hacked

Comment: Read the manuals again, you're doing it wrong

Comment: You forgot to put a value in your action attribute: `action=""` I assume you want to send it to the same page, so I recommend using `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]); ?>"` and I highly recommend reading the manuals posted by Fred -ii-, given that your code is extremely hackable amongst other things.

Comment: @Webeng Good point on that ^ they are intending on using it as self but using `htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[PHP_SELF])` is better.

Comment: yeah, XSS attacks are super common, and a simple `http://www.example.com/<script>alert('hello')</script>` written in the url to enter the site would already cause a breach.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and never store passwords as plain-text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the manuals on both of the following:

- `mysqli_select_db()` => http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php
- `mysqli_query()` => http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

That's why your code is failing. Both require a db connection and as the first parameter, it's all in there.

Plus, `mysqli_error()` also requires db connection be passed as a parameter.

- `mysqli_error()` => http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

While also checking for errors against your query; you're not doing that.

Sidenote about your connection.

You can actually get rid of `mysqli_select_db()` entirely, and just use all 4 parameters in `mysqli_connect()`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Example from the manual:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

---

**Passwords**

I also noticed that you may be storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

**Important sidenote about column length:**

If and when you do decide to use `password_hash()` or the compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/, it is important to note that if your present password column's length is anything lower than 60, it will need to be changed to that (or higher). The manual suggests a length of 255.

You will need to ALTER your column's length and start over with a new hash in order for it to take effect. Otherwise, MySQL will fail silently.

Other links of interest:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

Comment: That's quite a list of recommended password systems, but `password_hash()` should be #1 and the rest are on a "need to know" basis only. It's the only one that works reliably without a whole lot of specialized knowledge required.

Comment: You're right @tadman and I've made an edit. Thanks for the feedback, *cheers*